# Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role. DiscordJS v12

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a mutant role, well I can not restrict messages and reactions.

(node:7044) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.

```
const muteRole = message.guild.roles.create({
                    data: {
                        name: 'test - Muted',
                        color: '#F3FF00',
                    },
                });
                message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async (channel)=> {
                    await channel.overwritePermissions([
                        {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                            ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                        },
                    ]);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're actually looking for [`Channel.updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite). Either way, you're getting this error because both functions require a role or user id (otherwise, how will they know who to change permissions *for*).

```js
// create the role
message.guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'test - Muted',
    color: '#F3FF00',
  },
}).then((role) => {
  message.guild.channels.each((channel) => { // iterate through all channels
    channel.updatePermissions(role,  { // identify the role to update
      {
        SEND_MESSAGES: false, // set the overwrites
        ADD_REACTIONS: false,
      },
   );
  });
});
```